# How to feed XML tag content modifications back to BeautifulSoup correctly?

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, xml-parsing

I'm having some problems editing XML files with BeautifulSoup. I found tons of similar topics on stackoverflow and other places, but none had addressed this specific scenario. I'm editing contents of a tag that's essentially a list. The editing part works well, but I don't know how to send the modified contents back to the soup correctly.

Here is what I have so far:

```python
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

XMLsource = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<root>
  <dataTag>
    <id>14</id>
    <players>var:val : var1:val1 : var2:val2 : testr:testl</players>
    <active>0</active>
  </dataTag>
  <dataTag>
    <id>15</id>
    <players>1var:1val : 1var1:1val1 : 1var2:1val2 : 1testr:1testl</players>
    <active></active>
  </dataTag>
  <dataTag>
    <id>16</id>
    <players>2var:2val : 2var1:2val1 : this_var:some_val : 2var2:2val2 : 2testr:2testl</players>
    <active>1</active>
  </dataTag>
  <dataTag>
    <id>17</id>
    <players>3var:3val : 3var1:3val1 : 3var2:3val2 : 3testr:3testl</players>
    <active>1</active>
  </dataTag>
</root>
"""

myarray = []
searchList = ['string', 'string_1', 'string_2', 'string_3', 'this_']
delimiter = " : "

def listToString(lst):
    return (delimiter.join(lst))

soup = BeautifulSoup(XMLsource, 'xml')

for a in soup.find_all('players'):
    for each in a:
        tagContents = a.string
        goodContents = list(tagContents.split(" : "))
        length = len(goodContents)
        for element in range(length):
            e = goodContents[element]
            if e != '':
                myarray.append(e)
        for stuff in searchList:
            for i, elem in enumerate(myarray):
                if stuff in elem:
                    myarray.remove(elem)
    a.string = listToString(myarray)

print(soup)
```

The problem is `a.string = listToString(myarray)`. It just keeps adding `myarray` to the soup on each cycle in the main `for` loop. So the contents of the `<players>` tag stack up. You can run the code to see what I mean. It's a dummy code and it does't change the tag contents so it is clearer what the problem is.

It's now been three days testing and searching the Internetz. I changed the code a million times, but I'm not a programmer by trade, so my code is usually a trial and error process, and this time I just couldn't crack it. Can anyone fix the code for me, please?

Comment: there is no `string(_n)` in your xml, show us expected results

Comment: Hi uingtea, enumeration sounds like what I need to fix the issue. I updated the code to show you what it really does. It removes any matched string taken from `searchList` from any `<players>` tag. Here the string is `'this_var:some_val'` in the third `<players>` tag. The first two tags remain untouched and the string is removed from the third one. But in the resulting XML only the first tag is untouched. All the subsequent tags contain strings from all the preceding tags because don't know how to make BeautifulSoup place the results in their original tags only. That is what I need to fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after several sleepless nights I tried a different approach and lo and behold, it worked! So here it is in case somebody needs a script like this. There may still be some superfluous code in there, but it does what it is supposed to do. It removes strings defined in a list from any defined XML tag and it can also do it if the XML tag content is a list.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def listToString(lst):
    return (delimiter.join(lst))

XMLsource = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<root>
  <dataTag>
    <id>14</id>
    <players>var:val : var1:val1 : var2:val2 : testr:testl</players>
    <active>0</active>
  </dataTag>
  <dataTag>
    <id>15</id>
    <players>1var:1val : 1var1:1val1 : 1var2:1val2 : 1testr:1testl</players>
    <active></active>
  </dataTag>
  <dataTag>
    <id>16</id>
    <players>2var:2val : 2var1:2val1 : 2var2:2val2 : 2testr:2testl</players>
    <active>1</active>
  </dataTag>
  <dataTag>
    <id>17</id>
    <players>3var:3val : this_var:some_val : 3var1:3val1 : 3var2:3val2 : 3testr:3testl</players>
    <active>1</active>
  </dataTag>
</root>
"""

searchList = ['string', 'string_1', 'string_2', 'testr', 'this_v']

soup = BeautifulSoup(XMLsource, 'xml')
gamers = soup.find_all('players')
loopnum = len(gamers)
delimiter = " : "
newContents = []
badContents = []
goodContents = []
ii = 0

for xx in range(loopnum):
    newContents.clear()
    goodContents.clear()

    goodContents = gamers[xx].string
    goodContents = list(goodContents.split(" : "))

    for tagy in gamers[xx]:
        badContents.clear()

        for element in goodContents:
            e = element

            for stuff in searchList:
                if e != '':

                    if stuff in e:
                        badContents.append(e)

        newContents = [x for x in goodContents if x not in badContents]


    gamers[ii].string = listToString(newContents)
    ii += 1

print(soup)
```